# How to control battery usage by display in Xiaomi

Tags: applications, battery

I am using a Xiaomi redmi 1s phone which is of battery capacity 2050mAh. Most of the time when I checked the battery status, the screen uses about 55% to 70% of battery. Its display is of 720p. How can this consumption reduced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that Display is the most crucial use of battery, doesnt matter what you do, Display gonna take some battery juice.

Tips to reduce battery usage by Display

1. Use low brightness. This will affect your battery life most. In most case 30% is more than sufficient. For me, i put it at minimum at home and max outdoors.
2. Reduce the screen time out - set it to 30 sec or 1 min. I use 1 min.
3. Enable the Battery save mode in the settings.
4. Dont turn it on as much?

At the end, display still gonna majority of battery, the best way to deal it is to either buy new battery or Powerbank.

Kudos